# How to configure DNS BIND to work locally on one computer?

Tags: dns, bind

I want to do some changes to the BIND source code. In order to test those changes I want to be able to post queries to my local BIND server and for it to use only the local zone files.
I know how to make the zone files and somewhat the named.conf file but what should i put in /etc/resolv.conf?

In resolv.conf currently there is the line 
nameserver 192.168.0.1 
witch i guess is my router IP address and the queries go through the router to my ISP.

I want those queries to go to the local BIND server and to look for answers in the zone files i provided.

Is there a way for this using resolf.conf file or should i do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also make sure your test BIND is set to listen on 127.0.0.1 (and only 127.0.0.1) by changing the appropriate option in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` (if you are using Debian Linux, as an example).

You can also use the nslookup command to query a specific nameserver, as in `nslookup example.invalid 127.0.0.1`

To make it use only local zone files you want to make sure that `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` has no `forwarders` stanzas and that none of your zone files reference an external DNS server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

in /etc/resolv.conf.

However, a better idea is to use `dig` to test your configuration as it will not break your existing setup.

For instance if you use the command

```
dig @127.0.0.1 www.google.com
```

It will query the nameserver at 127.0.0.1 for the address of www.google.com.

Comment: Thanks Phil, i did try this before,but with no success. I guess I am doing something else wrong. Never the less this is helpfull a lot.